# Can some specific autodetected dependency be ignored upon rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, dependency-management, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

rpmbuild can autodetect dependencies by looking up shared libraries required by binaries included in the package and, while this is a good think almost every time, there are time when it is undesirable but only for some specific libraries. I am referring to the case where some binary file requires libraries that are not provided to the system via its rpm package management but installed directly by third party installers.

Now, the question is: is there a way to keep the autodetect feature active (comes in handy for the other binaries in the package) but ignore/remove only these specific libraries?

Something like

```
AutoReqIgnore : library1
AutoReqIgnore : library2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found a built-in way, but I [wrote a small script that I used as a filter](http://www.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/optional_rpm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use IPC::Open2;

# This quick script will run the native find-requires (first parameter)
# and then strip out packages we don't want listed.
open2(\*IN, \*OUT, @ARGV);
print OUT while (<STDIN>);
close(OUT);
my $list = join('', <IN>);

# Apply my filter(s):
$list =~ s/^libqt-mt.so.*?$//mg;

print $list;
```

You can put your own regular expression lines, in this example I removed `libqt-mt.so.*`

Then, in the `.spec` file:

```
# Note: 'global' evaluates NOW, 'define' allows recursion later...
%global _use_internal_dependency_generator 0
%global __find_requires_orig %{__find_requires}
%define __find_requires %{_builddir}/%{?buildsubdir}/build/find-requires %{__find_requires_orig}
```

As you can see, this script is in the source tarball under `/build/` .

Comment: Accepting answer without verification: I probably cannot verify it in the short term

Answer (score 4):

[As of rpm-4.9 (Fedora 15), rpm has a standard method to enable filtering](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:AutoProvidesAndRequiresFiltering) of the autogenerated dependencies.

For example, you can write

```
%global __requires_exclude ^libthirdpartyplugin.so$
```

Comment: *Finally*... It looks like [RHEL/CentOS 6](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) is still 4.8, but [RHEL/CentOS 7](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) bumps to 4.11.

Answer (score -1):

Legacy `rpm-4.8` and older (CentOS 6.x) have no filtering of autodetected dependencies. However, there's a workaround:

**Gzip the library in question before rpmbuild, and gunzip it after installation.** Dependency detection of rpmbuild will then ignore the file.

Example situation:

Your `awesome-project-1.2.3-4.i686.rpm` contains

- `libfoo.so` which depends on `libxx.so`
- `libbar.so` which depends on `libyy.so`
- `libbah.so` which depends on `libextra-3rdparty-stuff.so` that isn't shipped via RPM

You want to have the `libxx.so` and `libyy.so` in your RPM's dependencies, but not the `libextra-3rdparty-stuff.so`.

Now do the trick the rpm spec-file, say `awesome-project.spec`:

```
%prep
gzip "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/libbah.so"
exit

%post
gunzip -f "$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/usr/lib/libbah.so.gz
exit

%preun
gzip "$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/usr/lib/libbah.so" # so that `rpm -e` doesn't complain about missing file
exit
```

There you go. No more complaints on missing `libextra-3rdparty-stuff.so` when installing the RPM.