# Reassign values to %define variables in spec file - RPM

Tags: linux, rpm, specifications

When we define variables using the 
%define  tag in a spec file to build an RPM using the rpmbuild command ... is it possible to update its value on %pre and use it later on ?

Comment: Thanks for the notification! Corrected the word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

`%define` macros are always re-evaluated, top to bottom in the spec file, so you cannot have loops.

`%global` macros are one-time.

Example, from [another question concerning 'requires' processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212712/can-some-specific-autodetected-dependency-be-ignored-upon-rpmbuild):

```
%global _use_internal_dependency_generator 0
%global __find_requires_orig %{__find_requires}
%define __find_requires %{_builddir}/%{?buildsubdir}/build/find-requires %{__find_requires_orig}
```

If I had used `%define` to declare `__find_requires_orig`, it would error out with a macro loop.

If this doesn't answer your question, please elaborate what information you are looking for, or your end goal.

---

ETA:

The `%pre` and `%post` sections will already have the macros hard-coded from when the RPM is built. If you need additional run-time decisions to be made, they will need to be done in those shell scripts.

Comment: Ah i understand, so is it possible to assign some value to any variable and use it in another tag. E.g. I do some verification in the %pre tag and create a variable then use its new value in %install tag ?

Comment: No, you can't do that with RPM variables, unless you meant the `%prep` section. `%pre` is executed on the *target* machine, where `%install` was used when building the RPM.

Comment: No, again, `%pre` and `%post` are on the target machine, where every macro has been hard-coded in the RPM file at that point. You'd have to use regular shell variables, and they need to be re-evaluated in each section.

Comment: for the moment, what i did was create a temporary file in /temp folder then delete it on exit of rpm. Is that ok ?

Comment: That should be fine if it was only in `%pre` and `%post`, i.e. you didn't write the file in `%install` and expect it to be there for `%pre`. And also assuming that you created the file in a secure manner with something like `mktemp` since RPM installs run as `root`.

Comment: ok thats great :)
can you please update your answer so that i may mark it correct. And thanks once again

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco - what if I want to define the value of a variable in the `%prep` section and use it in the `%build` and `%install` sections? is it possible?