# rpm installs fails even though dependent perl module is installed

Tags: perl-module, rpm, rpmbuild

I am building rpm package for internal software. It contains binaries and perl script/modules. During build process rpmbuild automatically scans perl code and builds dependency perl modules including DBD:mysql.
When I try to install the software package rpm fails with error that it cannot find DBD::mysql. DBD::mysql is installed on the system.

```
# rpm -ivh conserver-admin-8.1.18-.el5.CME_1.0.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(DBD::mysql) is needed by conserver-admin-8.1.18-.el5.CME_1.0.x86_64

# rpm -qp --requires conserver-admin-8.1.18-.el5.CME_1.0.x86_64.rpm
/bin/ksh  
/bin/sh  
/usr/bin/perl  
perl(CMEconserver)  
perl(DBD::mysql)  
perl(DBI)  
perl(Data::Dumper)  
perl(Exporter)  
perl(FindBin)  
perl(Getopt::Std)  
perl(POSIX)  
perl(Socket)  
perl(lib)  
perl(strict)  
perl(warnings)  
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1`
```

The perl module is installed on the system

```
# perl -e 'use DBD::mysql;'
#
```

All of the perl modules in the dependency list are installed on the system and I can run the script without any problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. rpm will only know about the package that was installed using rpm. I had downloaded the DBD::mysql source and manually compiled and installed it on my system.

I added

```
AutoReq: no
```

to my spec file turn of dependency check during build.
This could be dangerous so be careful before you use it.

Comment: You applied a really big hammer. ;) I would recommend turning it back on and getting the list of what it required. Then turn it off, and manually add `Requires` tags to the spec file for each one. Possibly something like `/usr/lib/perl/site-perl/etcetcetc/DBD/mysql.pm` as well (which should be fine since you're saying the RPM is only used internally).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to filter out the automatic dependency script's output. I [document here how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228605/836748).

Comment: Thanks, I will try your script in future. In this particular case I was able to use heavy hammer because mysql was the only non-standard perl package I was using. Due to other requirements I had to split my package into two RPMs, one with binary executables and one with perl code only. I turned of AutoReq in the perl package.