# is RPM build conditional on build or on install?

Tags: redhat, rpmbuild

I've already read this thread [RPM conditional Requires in spec file possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991975/rpm-conditional-requires-in-spec-file-possible) but I just want to make sure with a yes/no answer.

I have the following in my spec file:
(from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag)

```
%if 0%{?rhel}  == 6 || 0%{?rhel} == 7
Requires: XXX
%else
Requires: YYY
%endif
```

Does it mean that when I **build** the rpm if I'm building on RHEL 6 or 7 then the rpm would require XXX or does it mean that the rpm I have built will require XXX or YYY based on the **installation** target?

Please be simple in your answer, there is no need of overkill.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build-time. You need to build two different RPMs for the two different distros.