# Corresponding package names in "yum" from "apt-get"

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, redhat, yum, apt-get, rhel7

My program has the following dependencies in Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install unzip wget
apt-get install mesa-common-dev -y
apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
apt-get install libfontconfig1 -y
apt-get install libglib2.0-0 -y
apt-get install libxcursor-dev libxtst-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev -y
apt-get install libxss-dev libxcomposite-dev libxslt1-dev -y
apt-get install libasound2-dev -y
```

Now I also need to deploy on RHEL which uses "yum" instead of "apt-get" so my question is what is the "yum" equivalent of all the packages used above. Is there a table where they are mapped? Basically for each package above I want to know or how to find out the "yum" repository equivalent.

Also, if I'm writing a SPEC file with BuildRequires...are they all yum package names because RPM is mainly for RedHat?

Answer (score 2):

RHEL  variants will use `-devel` convention instead of `-dev` from debian world. Beside that the names would be similar, a `yum search PKG` would point out the right direction

If things get hard you can use `dpkg -L PKG`, grab a key file and `yum whatprovides FILE` to find out what packages provides that file.

Comment: Thanks for responding...much appreciated. I figured out all the mappings from "apt-get" to "yum" through: http://rosindex.github.io. I did have a follow up question...in the SPEC file for RPM...are the package names for "BuildRequire" mainly in "yum" repo or "apt-get" or it can be either?

Comment: So for my RPM SPEC file, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04+, RHEL 7+, and CentOS 7+...now in my SPEC file how do I include a conditional when dealing with the package names. For example if I'm Ubuntu I want to BuildRequire apt-get specific package names as a oppose to Red Hat "yum" package names.

Comment: You have some options, using conditionals is one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991975/rpm-conditional-requires-in-spec-file-possible. You can also split the spec to support multiple hosts and it will build multiple RPM files each one with its own build requires I guess. What I can't understand is that you're building a rpm for ubuntu? This doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: I'll relieve your confusion. I am tossing out conditionals...everything in our RPM spec file needs to be in yum for RedHat. I was just a bit confused. Our build server is in Ubuntu but we are trying to support all build types so when we build we produce a tar, deb, and an RPM file. You are right RPM content shouldn't be for Ubuntu.

Comment: Ohh I see, well you may be able to build multiple RPMS from a single machine. Take a look at tito [1] and mock [2], it may help you: [1] https://github.com/dgoodwin/tito [2] https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki